# Есть смысл изучать javascript если я планирую писать сайты в asp,net?

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Я собираюсь изучать asp.net Razor и перед этим я решил изучить(ну или хотя бы познакомится) с html и css. Куда не смотри говорят надо ещё изучать php и js. А есть ли смысл? Мой основной язык это c# и мне очень приятна идея писать в asp.net. 
Может мне стоит тогда хотя бы познакомиться как с js так и с php? Я просто не знаю.

Comment: php не нужен, забудьте и не вспоминайте это слово:) А с js скорей всего придётся познакомиться. Конечно можно допустить такое, что не придётся самолично работать над фронтэндом вообще никак и на своём asp.net генерить только json в худшем случае. то тогда и js не нужен.

Comment: не поймите неправильно, такие вопросы связанные с выбором языка лучше не задавать на подобных ресурсов, потому что каждый топит за свой язык. профессиональная этика:) лично моя оценка, каждый из этих языков очень актуальны в наше время, возьмите один из этих языков, изучите и попробуйте устроиться куда-нибудь стажером, а после уверен вы сами определите, чего вам больше не хватает, возможно даже смените профессиональную область вместо сайтов на мобильные приложения. если понадобится здесь примерные вопросы на собеседованиях по C# https://metanit.com/sharp/interview/. главное не бояться критики)

Answer (score 0):

Вам в любом случаи стоит изучать JS(не Php). Весь код который вы будете писать на Razor все равно в конечном итоге рендериться браузером как JS. Да и вообще все еще без дополнительных скриптов на странице в вед разработке и в том числе на C# нет смысла. Дальше вы скорее всего будете изучать так же SPA(Angular, React, Vue) И тут как не крути прийдеться так же учить JS. Php во все этих случая не нужен, но без JS никуда) да и стыдно его не знать после C#